# Yii2 Internationalization with code instead of a whole sentence

Tags: yii2, internationalization

I'm currently working on internationalization for a website using Yii2.

Usually, I use it like this:

```
Yii::t('frontend', 'Do you have something to eat?')
```

Then, I have two folders in common\messages called en-EN and id-ID. Each has frontend.php inside of it.

**en-EN/frontend.php**

```
return [
    
];
```

**id-ID/frontend.php**

```
return [
    'Do you have something to eat?' => 'Ada yang bisa dimakan?'
];
```

It works fine, but I don't think it's practical because the sentence is too long and one character miss will not work.

So I tried using something like this:

```
Yii::t('frontend', 'My.Random.Sentence');
```

**en-EN/frontend.php**

```
return [
    'My.Random.Sentence' => 'Do you have something to eat?',
];
```

**id-ID/frontend.php**

```
return [
    'My.Random.Sentence' => 'Ada yang bisa dimakan?'
];
```

It only works for id-ID, but when I change back to english, it still displays My.Random.Sentence instead of Do you have something to eat.

This is my config in **i18n.php**

```
return [
    'sourcePath' => __DIR__. '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'languages' => ['en-EN','id-ID'],
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'only' => ['*.php'],
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
        '/vendor',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
    'messagePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'messages',
    'overwrite' => true,
];
```

And this is in **frontend/config/main.php**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en-US';

return [
    // other options

    'language' => $_SESSION['lang'],
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-EN',
    'components' => [
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'frontend*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                ],
                'backend*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    //other options
];
```

Is this not possible? What is the correct way for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `i18n` component doesn't translate the string when `$sourceLanguage` and `$language` are same. Instead it returns the source string.

But fortunately you can force it to translate the strings even when the `$sourceLanguage` and `$language` properties are same. To do that you need to set `$forceTranslation` property of `MessageSource` to true. You can do it in you **frontend/config/main.php** like this:

```php
return [
    // other options 
    'components' => [
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'frontend*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                    'forceTranslation' => true,
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],

    //other options
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried but it's not working

Comment: @HenryGunawan I've just noticed that you use `en-EN` in your i18n.php config (and folder name) but you set the `$_SESSION['lang']` to `en-US` when the session is not set. That's probably why it's not working for you.

Comment: Ah! yes you're right. It's because of en-EN and en-US. I change all of them to en-EN and it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And forceTranslation is a must too. I tried deleting it and it didn't work.